# MVC 5 collection not mapped to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I've done this before, but had to freshen up my knowledge when I couldn't get it to work.

I'm basically creating a list of checkboxes. I've reproduced this guide:https://exceptionnotfound.net/simple-checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc/

I was totally unable to get the items back from a `HttpPost` and could not understand why. The HTML looked fine, having id's and names like I expected, "Checks_0__IsChecked" "Checks[0].IsChecked" etc.

When all fails, try to isolate the problem - so I created a brand new web application and copied my checkbox model, my editor template and created an identical "create" scenario - which to my surprise **worked just as expected**.

Looking at the form values (`Request.Form`) it contained the same key/value pairs and the model was mapped correctly.

Any suggestions as to what might be the issue, or how to proceed in determining the cause?

Editor template for checkbox model:

```
@model CheckBoxViewModel

<div class="form-check">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDisabled)
    @if (Model.IsDisabled)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsChecked, new { @class = "form-check-input", @disabled = "disabled" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsChecked, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
    }
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsChecked, Model.Text, new { @class = "form-check-label" })
</div>
```

Editor template for the model:

```
@model ScheduledTriggerViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Checks)
```

The view:

```
@model ScheduledTriggerViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

**EDIT**
The route configuration is the same except an additional route (Debug/Logs/{year}/{month}) which is placed first. The route does not seem like the issue as the action gets hit, and other form values are mapped correctly.

I check the `Request.Form` values in the beginning inside the action method. The action signatures are the same except one being `async Task<ActionResult>` while the other is just `ActionResult`

The form contains all checkboxes with names like `Checks[0].IsChecked` etc. up to count-1.

None of the checkboxes are disabled in the HTML.

I've also added Autofac to the test project to check if it somehow handled the model binding process, but it did no difference.

**UPDATE**
I've created a new controller, a new model and new editor templates that are exactly the same as the original except for the model name.

The model is an exact copy of the other model.

This controller/view/editortemplates works as intended - but **NOT** as expected, as I was sure the problem would remain.

I changed the troublesome controller to use the new model and it worked... i have no idea why, since they are identical. I did not have to change anything in the views to perform the replacement.

Since they are equal in content, I'm out of ideas of what might be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Where are you checking Request.Form? Same Action signatures? Routes?

Comment: `The HTML looked fine, having id's and names like I expected, "Checks_0__IsChecked" "Checks[0].IsChecked" etc.` - does the `etc` mean that there are `"Checks_1__IsChecked" "Checks[1].IsChecked"`, `"Checks_2__IsChecked" "Checks[2].IsChecked"` etc, from 0 to count-1, in that order?

Comment: You have an `if` condition that means that some checkboxes will be disabled. Disabled controls do not submit a value, therefore the value of those will always be `false` in the POST method

Comment: I've updated my post wit answers to the questions.

Comment: Compare web.config files, especially the appConfig section?

Comment: Anything in particular i should look for? I do not have any appConfig section.